# Fix 'Add Role' Option not there in wordpress 5.2.2

Tags: users, user-roles

I am making my website on the net and practicing it on localhost wordpress. I want to add a new role in my wordpress, but in both my sites(localhost and internet) I can't find the option to add a role. I went to google for this problem but I didn't found an answer. I am using an custom theme based on 'Twenty Nineteen' if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

"Add Role" isn't an option in WordPress, and never has been. If you want to add a role you'll need a plugin like [User Role Editor](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) or [Members](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

If you want to add a role with code, you can do this with the `add_role()` function:

```
add_role(
    'member', 
    'Member', 
    [
        'edit_posts' => true,
    ]
);
```

Just be aware that roles are persistent, so this function should only be run once on theme/plugin activation.

Comment: And what does the first  and second string represent and where to put it